# PHP GET gathered in one file?

Tags: php, get

I got 12 .php files with this code:

```
if($_GET['u']){
  $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/".$_GET['u'].".png");
  $destp = imagecreate(1200, 1800);
  imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 20, 20, 1200, 1800, 8, 12);
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  imagepng($destp);
}
```

Yes only thing that seperates the different files is the positions of the image. Now can I have many of that lines in PHP? I tried taking that line and a line from another file and just renamed *u* to *b* in that case but it didn't work....

I tried like this without any good result (only u worked):

```
if($_GET['u']){
   $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/".$_GET['u'].".png");
   $destp = imagecreate(1200, 1800); 
   imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 20, 20, 1200, 1800, 8, 12);
   header('Content-type: image/png');
   imagepng($destp);
}
if($_GET['b']){
   $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/".$_GET['b'].".png");
   $destp = imagecreate(600, 1800);
   imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 16, 20, 600, 1800, 4, 12);
   header('Content-type: image/png');
   imagepng($destp);
}
```

So Do anyone know how to kinda put all my 12 lines of code from 12 PHP files into 1 php file? :/

Thanks in advance, enji

Comment: We can haz some line breakz plz?

Comment: I mean that's a terrifically long line that I would kill any of my colleagues for writing! O_O

Comment: I just do it to save space ^-^

Comment: What for? Are you limited in space? Tip: readability always trumps verboseness. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in this case, since the file is always the same path, you should just add a second `$_GET` and use it as a type with a switch:

```
image.php?u=water&position=2

if($_GET['u']){
    $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/".$_GET['u'].".png");
    switch($_GET['position']){
        case '1':
            $destp = imagecreate(1200, 1800); 
            imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 20, 20, 1200, 1800, 8, 12);
            break;
        case '2':
            $destp = imagecreate(600, 1800);
            imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 16, 20, 600, 1800, 4, 12);
            break;
    }
   header('Content-type: image/png');
   imagepng($destp);
}
```

I'll second webjawns.com's warning to never trust the input value of a `$_GET`. serialworm offers an very easy way of filtering the input with `$u = strip_tags($_GET['u']);`

Comment: It didn't work. I got this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CASE in /var/www/vhosts/enji.se/subdomains/skin/httpdocs/parts.php on line 5

Answer (score 3):

First, I want to address a pressing security hole in your code.  Using any request parameters without filtering is asking for trouble.  ALWAYS filter `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, etc., variables before using them.  In short, ensure that you do some kind of escaping/filtering on `$_GET['u']` and `$_GET['b']`.  For example, if you know that both parameters will only contain alphanumeric characters, use the following:

```
// Remove non-alphanumeric characters from $_GET['u']
$filtered = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $_GET['u']);
```

Although trite, one should always take the following maxim into account when developing:

> NEVER TRUST THE USER!

Comment: NEVER TRUST THE USER! can never be stressed enough.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to *functions* and the world of *reusable code*. Put that code into a function, put that function into a file, include that file in your other files, call the function:

```
// thumbnail.php
function outputSkinThumbnail($skin) {
    $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/$skin.png");
    $destp = imagecreate(1200, 1800);
    imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 20, 20, 1200, 1800, 8, 12);
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($destp);
}

// some other file
require_once 'thumbnail.php';
if (!empty($_GET['u'])) {
    outputSkinThumbnail($_GET['u']);
}
```

Comment: how can that make me have all the different "if's" in one file? xD I'm totally new to PHP but I know JavaScript :P Oh the project is live here http://skin.enji.se/?user=enjikaka&hat?true All those different part of the "player" is 1 PHP file each. for Example there is http://skin.enji.se/head.php?u=enjikaka

Comment: The point is that the repetitive part of the code is in one file only. You could put the condition into that function as well and use the GET name as the variable, like `if (!empty($_GET[$name])) …` and call it like `outputSkinThumbnail('u')`, but I wouldn't recommend that, since that makes the function only usable with $_GET variables, which may be undesirable. Yes, you'll still have a little bit of repetition with the `if` part, but this is about the best balance of [DRYness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) and flexibility you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function:

```
function showThumb($u){
    if($u){
        $srcp = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.minecraft.net/skin/". $u .".png");
        $destp = imagecreate(1200, 1800);
        imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 20, 20, 1200, 1800, 8, 12);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($destp);
     }
}
```

You should check the $_GET value for malicious tags

```
$u = strip_tags($_GET['u']);
```

And call it like:

```
showThumb($u);
```